# Installed Soundux, but won't open

Tags: sound, software-installation, deb

I have been trying to install Soundux.

I got the .deb and installed...however it will not open. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Ubuntu 22.04

installed via the https://soundux.rocks/download using .deb

Comment: It is unclear what distro is used, and how Soundux was installed.

Comment: Are you sure this app works with Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: @David I got to work, now it doesn't. But their github states it works on Ubuntu

Comment: @Walt it probably works on *older* Ubuntu.  I should note that since the switch to OpenSSL 3.0 and the removal of `libssl` and `libcrypto` 1.1 it has caused some things to not function.  This is a problem with those older softwares suffering bitrot or not being updated to work with newer OpenSSL - and being compiled against *older* libraries which in turn is why they're broken here.  Ideally the people who develop the package will fix that

Answer (score 0):

Check `/var/logs/syslog` for soundux errors.  After installing and trying to run Soundux on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, I found these errors:

```
/opt/soundux/soundux: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

/opt/soundux/soundux: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It's looking for these files in `/usr/lib`, which are missing.  I happened to have copies of these files already in the lib for a different application (piavpn), so I copied them to `/usr/lib` and that fixed the issue.